# form.validate_on_submit() never runs for my form

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-5, flask-wtforms

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDyv7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDyv7.png)]

Python code

[image: [![H](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qsea.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qsea.png)]

HTML Code

I have POST as my method, but whenever I click on submit nothing happens?

Comment: I'm not able to see the whole code there, so I'm sorry about my silly question: Do you have the `<form>` tag and the "csrf token" in the HTML code? Just like in their [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/quickstart/#creating-forms).

Comment: It would make it easier for others to help you if you replace the images in your post with the raw code.

Comment: I was missing the csrf token, thanks